# Singly linked list queue class

Tags: c++, queue

I have a `Queue` class that is basically a single linked list. It has 2 remove methods. What would be the cleanest way to avoid duplication of the code? Only the comparisons in methods are different.

```
int Queue::remove(const string& substring)
{
    // Loop through the queue list
    size_t found;
    found = current_job->description.find(substring)
    if (found != string::npos) {
        // Remove job.
    }
    // Return the amount of removed jobs.   
}

int Queue::remove(int priority)
{
    // Loop through the queue list
    if (current_job->priority == priority) {
        // Remove job.
    }
    // Return the amount of removed jobs.     
}
```

I thought a template solution as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9411448), but in this case, the comparison function has different arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can abstract out the thing that changes, the comparison expression, into a predicate for a template function.

```
class PriorityMatch
{
    int priority_;
public:
    explicit PriorityMatch(int priority)
        : priority_(priority) {}

    bool operator()(const Job& job)
    {
        return job->priority == priority_;
    }
};

class DescriptionMatch
{
    std::string substring_;
public:
    explicit DescriptionMatch(const std::string& substring)
        : substring_(substring) {}

    bool operator()(const Job& job)
    {
        return job->description.find(substring_) != std::string::npos;
    }
};

template<class Predicate>
int Queue::remove(Predicate predicate)
{
    // Loop through the queue list
    if (predicate(current_job)) {
        // Remove job.
    }
    // Return the amount of removed jobs.     
}

int Queue::remove(const string& substring)
{
    return remove(DescriptionMatch(substring));
}

int Queue::remove(int priority)
{
    return remove(PriorityMatch(substring));
}
```

Or in C++11:

```
template<class Predicate>
int Queue::remove(Predicate predicate)
{
    // Loop through the queue list
    if (predicate(current_job)) {
        // Remove job.
    }
    // Return the amount of removed jobs.     
}

int Queue::remove(const string& substring)
{
    return remove([](const Job& job){
        return job->description.find(substring) != std::string::npos;
    });
}

int Queue::remove(int priority)
{
    return remove([](const Job& job){
        return job->priority == priority;
    });
}
```

Comment: +1. The only difference; I usually make simple functors like `PriorityMatch` and `DescriptionMatch` private member `structures` rather than `classes`. This is because I do not seem them as real object but rather as `property bags` that are used to transport information to a call site.

Comment: @LokiAstari: What do you mean?  The `struct` and `class` keywords are almost synonyms.

Comment: @AntonGolov: I use struct for property bags. Its not anything major just a stylistic thing that I have adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a comment, I think that renaming both member functions to `Queue::removeBySubstring` and `Queue::removeByPriority` could improve code readability at the client side.